# seBackupPrivilige required when backing up Application Event Log with WMI

Tags: c#, security, wmi

I have a function that archives an event log to a file in a required format.

I'm testing against the windows event logs,`Application`,`Security`and`System`. In all tests the code is run with local administrator privileges.

On my development environment the code backs up the each logfile, to what we name an "*.evt" file, succesfully.

On the target reference system the`Security`and`System`logs work correctly but processing the `Application`log throws a `ManagementException`.

An interogation of the exception is included below. My questions are, am I right to assume this is a security privileges issue? What code changes will make this code work for all my desired cases? Failing a definite answer, your thoughts and ideas are appreciated.

> ErrorCode: AccessDenied
>
> ErrorInformation: Description: Opened the logfile but failed to back it up, privilige error
>
> Operation: ExecMethod
>
> ParameterInfo: Win32_NTEventlogFile.Name="C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\AppEvent.Evt"
>
> PrivilegesNotHeld:-
>       SeBackupPrivilege
>
> PrivilegesRequired:-
>       SeBackupPrivilege
>
> ProviderName: WinMgmt
>
> StatusCode: 2147749891

```
using System.Management;
/* ... Omitted for brevity */

public static void WMIBackup(String logName, String targetFile)
{
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
    scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
        String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventLog WHERE LogFileName={0}", 
            logName)
    );

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher search = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
    {
        var logs = search.Get();
        if (logs.Count != 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("logName not found");

        foreach (ManagementObject log in logs)
        {
            ManagementClass eventLogClass = 
                new ManagementClass("Win32_NTEventLogFile");
            ManangementBaseObject params = 
                eventLogClass.GetMethodParameters("BackupEventLog");
            params["ArchiveFileName"] = targetFile;
            log.InvokeMethod(
                "BackupEventLog",
                params,
                new InvokeMethodOptions(
                    null, 
                    InvokeMethodOptions.InfiniteTimeout)
            );
        } 
    }
}
```

All data is transcribed so apologies for errata.

Comment: Dammit, I copied this code one to one and it started failing. It took me awhile to see why. It turns out he messed up typing the query. It should be `Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile Where LogFileName={0}` instead.

Comment: @c00000fd updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had issues accessing WMI and/or COM interfaces in the past.  It would work on one system and fail on another.

I found that the the error did not happen if you retried.  I'd suggest that when it fails, you wait for a short period (half a second or so) and retry.

My code has a retry loop around all the COM and WMI calls similar to this sample:

```
int errorCount = 0;
bool success = false;
while (!success || errorCount < maxRetryCount)
{
    try
    {
         /* Call to WMI interface */
         DoSomething();
         success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         if (errorCount < maxRetryCount)
         {
             logWarning(ex);
         }
         else
         {
             logError(ex);
             throw; /* pass exception up the stack 
             or break and handle failure below */
         }
    }
}
if (!success)
{
    /* Handle failure */
}
```

Never did work out what the underlying issue was, but this works for me.

Comment: Well, this worked for me. Turns out it was the first attempt that failed, not the Application Log in paticular.